# python - update thread variable

Tags: python, multithreading

how do I update a variable inside a running thread, which is an infinite loop based on such variable?
a simplified version of what I tried is what follows, to no results of course, and I can't find any pointer.

```
import some_module as mod
import threading

class thr (threading.Thread):
    NUM = 5  # set a default value to start the script
    def run (self):
        mod.NUM = NUM
        mod.main_loop()

try:
    thr().start()
    time.sleep(1)
    thr().NUM = 2
    time.sleep(1)
    thr().NUM = 6
    time.sleep(1)
    thr().NUM = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a new thread each time you "call" (i.e. instantiate) `thr`. Change your code to

```
t = thr()
t.start()
time.sleep(1)
t.NUM = 2
time.sleep(1)
t.NUM = 6
time.sleep(1)
t.NUM = 8
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't update the variable inside the infinite loop

Comment: It updates the `NUM` variable in the thread object instance... to update `mod.NUM` just do that with `mod.NUM = 2` ... etc.

Comment: that far I've gotten already, my problem here is that the updated variable is not being fed to the infinite loop...

Comment: @nxet: what loop? you're asking what is the problem in code not shown? My wild guess is that the statement at line 42 in some_module.py contains a mistake... but it's a VERY wild guess :-D

Comment: man I was this close to open up `some_module.py` and see for any error there :/ this is how lost I am here.
basically the thread I'm launching has an infinite loop within, and the variable I want to update is what the loop parses to execute.
I thought it was irrelevant, but at this point it might be worth noting that some_module.py actually is a multiplexing script. basically I say '5 7' to the module, and it runs infinitely multiplexing said values between two led bars (extremely roughly explained). I need to update the value and see the change reflected with the leds

Comment: Modules in Python are (normally) singletons. This means that you cannot have one "instance" of a module running with some global values and another instance running with other global values. This is technically possible by messing with `sys.modules` but only in very few cases you really want to do that. What you should do instead is changing `some_module.py` so that it becomes a `class` that can be multiply instanced (once per thread). May be you should just take the code and put into `thr` directly...

Comment: that's my whole point, I don't want multiple instances.
I hope I didn't get wrong your comment, but instead of running a new instance everytime NUM needs to be updated, I just want the loop inside the thread to notice that change and run accordingly.
I've tried a `while NUM == NUM` inside a while True loop (always inside the imported module), to see if that was noticing the change and then restarting the loop, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try use queue for change NUM variable.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Check examples here :

https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/

Generally speakinig the queue allows You send data between threads. Use `get()` for getting data from queue and `put()` for put data to queue.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a bit too generic for my limited knowledge of the language, and reading the link provided didn't help much unfortunately. can you please elaborate a bit more on this? thanks a lot

Comment: the second link was way more helpful. but am I wrong to assume I'm forced to kill and spawn a new thread everytime?

Comment: @nxet I don`t uderstand :)What mean - "I'm forced to kill and spawn a new thread everytime?"